# Does there exist a known example of Riemannian manifold who its sectional curvature admit both zero and positive values?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Does there exist a known example of Riemannian manifold who its sectional curvature admit both zero and positive values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $2$-manifolds, the sectional curvature is the Gauss curvature, see

[Sectional Curvature, Gauss curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648901/sectional-curvature-gauss-curvature)

*Theorem (From Do Carmo's book, p. 282, see below):* Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a connected, regular, compact, orientable surface which is not homeomorphic to a sphere. Then there are points on $S$ where the Gaussian curvature is positive, negative, and zero.

Proof: [Compact surface with Gaussian curvature is positive, negative, and zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431686/compact-surface-with-gaussian-curvature-is-positive-negative-and-zero)

See [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjejO_t1sDXAhXOh7QKHZ45ATQQFgg2MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.win.tue.nl%2F~rvhassel%2FOnderwijs%2FTensor-ConTeX-Bib%2FExamples-diff-geom%2FTorus-diff-geom%2Ftorus-together.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3qwBSI7lABzgf6bikojjjH) for a nice example on the $2$-torus.

Comment: Thanks, Is this theorem true is higher dimensions?

Comment: Well, you could just take direct products, e.g. $T^2 \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to obtain higher-dimensional examples.